# Conditional with number1 == number2 (of type Long) is never true?

Tags: java, android

this code is supposed to list recent calls with recent same nos skipped but they are being displayed, please help

```
             //code
              Long number0=(long) 0;   
          // loop through cursor 
          while(mCallCursor.moveToNext()){
              Long number1 = mCallCursor.getLong(0);
              if(number1==number0)
                  continue;
              else
                  number0=number1;
              if(mCallCursor.getString(2)!=null){
                  String name = mCallCursor.getString(2);
                  System.out.println(name);
              }
              else
                  System.out.println(number1);

          }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
if(number1==number0)
```

use

```
if(number1.equals(number0))
```

Two `Long` values can satisfy `equals` without being `==`.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why it is not working is that Long 's are objects and == operator works as it is testing equalities of two objects not the long values stored in these objects. On the other hand a long is not an object but a primitive.

```
if((long)number2 == (long)number1)
```

shall work as well.